# RegisterClientScriptBlock ASP.net

Tags: javascript

I want to execute alert when user clicks LinkButton1.It is not working?

```
protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "abc", "<script language=javascript>alert(hi)</script>");
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mistyped the function name. Change `aler` to `alert`. Also, you forgot the delimiters around the string that you are trying to alert.

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "abc", "alert('hi');", true);
```

Answer (score 1):

use the below

```
<linkButton runat="server" id="lnk1" OnClientClick="alert('hi');" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope your sample doesn't have a typo, but you are calling "aler" instead of "alert"!

Also, this doesn't define that your button would run this script when the user clicks the link button, it'll be executed when the page gets loaded.

For having such behavior, you need to use the "OnClientClick" control's property, and set there the name of the function - event handler - that would do the alert.

linkButton1.OnClientClick = "myEventHandler";

And define your script in some JavaScript file or by registering a client script block during the pre-render event of your container control or page.